# Mi codigo se salta el: std::getline()

Tags: c++

Me pasa que yo cuando compilo mi programa, este se salta la función `std::getline()`, y salta a la próxima linea de código sin pedir el input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

#define endl "\n"
#define clearConsole system("clear");
#define PAUSE system("PAUSE");

void vbsSpanish()
{
    std::ofstream virus;
    std::string nombreVirus;
    std::cout << "Ahora dime el nombre de tu virus: " << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, nombreVirus);
    virus << nombreVirus;
}
```

[image: Captura]

Gracias.

NOTA: Yo utilizo `std::getline()` para obtener un input con espacios.

Comment: No veo lo que pone en la captura de pantalla porque soy daltónico. ¿Por qué no pones el texto del error?

Comment: Es que cuando el programa despliega el siguiente texto: "Ahora dime el nombre de tu virus:", debería pedir un input con getline() pero el compilador salta el getline() y nunca pide el input.

Comment: Eso que comentas me parece hermoso y bello. Pero sigo sin poder ver el contenido de tu captura de pantalla. ¿No podrías poner el texto del error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se qué pretendes conseguir con el código que compartes, pero tal y como está redactado pierdes la información que recopilas por consola:

```
void vbsSpanish()
{
    // Crear un flujo de salida a archivo, sin asignarle ningún archivo.
    std::ofstream virus;
    std::string nombreVirus;
    // Leer la consola en una cadena.
    std::cout << "Ahora dime el nombre de tu virus: " << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, nombreVirus); 
    // Enviar la cadena al flujo de salida que al no tener asignado archivo, se pierde.
    virus << nombreVirus;
}
```

Si cambias el flujo de salida por la salida en consola, verás que la información se ha leído correctamente:

```
void vbsSpanish()
{
    std::string nombreVirus;
    std::cout << "Ahora dime el nombre de tu virus: \n";
    std::getline(std::cin, nombreVirus); 
    std::cout << nombreVirus;
    //   ^^^^ <--- Consola.
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsIwEEXXzVcMdVNBpbhsi6C/ILhykyZDO9BOSh7diN8e4wOs4Gzn3HuumqZtp1SMK2I1BI3QkHHeohwPQsyGNMytO0@SyfXFWtwEpHNeV1WiiDtgM7YWL2SDq79PZYKHpoH82BsrQdOIgMMHhqTxAeZnpoIr54tgh34gxuLdQrxZCtZ/DD/@uxDEHkZJ/BqbLcfXIrPog2UoExnjSVprPDrY70rxAA)</kbd>.